# python generator expressions in class definitions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I'm writing a simple class in Python 2.7.13 and I ran into a surprising error:

```
class X(object):
    T = 'test {}'

    A1 = [x for x in T]  # ok
    A2 = tuple([x for x in T])  # ok
    A3 = tuple(x for x in T)  # ok

    B1 = [T.format(x) for x in (1,2)]  # ok
    B2 = tuple([T.format(x) for x in (1,2)])  # ok
    B3 = tuple(T.format(x) for x in (1,2))  # NameError
```

All of the above work except the line defining B3 which gives `NameError: global name 'T' is not defined`.

I'm curious exactly why that line is the only one giving an error. I had been writing `tuple(...)` as if it were equivalent to `tuple([...])` but it seems that they are not the same after all.

I also checked and Python 3.4.3 gives an error on the lines defining `B1`, `B2` and `B3` which at least seems more consistent.

Comment: Just don't use comprehensions and genexps inside a class definition. It doesn't work. There's a good dupe around here somewhere.

Comment: The issue is not the tuple call, but what's inside it. `[T.format(x)...]` is a list comprehension, whereas `(T.format(x)...)` is a generator expression. Python lets you omit the surrounding parentheses if a generator expression is the only parameter to a callable.

Comment: In Python 3, you'd get the same error for all three `B*` definitions.

Comment: And @user2357112: was faster in locating my own answer than I was. :-)

Comment: What about the `A*` definitions? It's interesting that they work in all pythons. @MartijnPieters your other answer is remarkably complete! So I'm not arguing this is a duplicate, I just thought a brief answer to why the `A*` definitions are okay might be helpful for others.

Comment: @nonagon: there `T` is the iterable for the top-level `for` loop, which is passed into the function that is generated to handle the generator expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters gotcha - makes sense. Thank you!!